# Tomcat default application without changing context

Tags: tomcat, root

I made a web application and put it in tomcat webapps folder as in.war

For making it accessible, I added a meta redirect entry in index.html in ROOT folder so that when some one 
types www.mydomain.com, he gets redirected to www.mydomain.com/in

I have lot of pages in my website which are like www.mydomain.com/in/rest/page

Now what I want is that my application to become root application.

So that, when some one types www.mydomain.com, he can see my home page on that url itself without any redirection.

But all the old links should also work, as all my page shave already been crawled and indexed by major search engines.

Please tell me how to do that in the best possible way.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want your webapp to be the "root" webapp (that is, accessed starting with "/"), then you'll want to re-name your WAR file to ROOT.war (case is important, even on case-insensitive filesystems).

After that, you'll want to map all your old URLs to the new ones. Here's one way:

Get yourself a copy of urlrewrite (http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). Install it and configure it in your newly-renamed ROOT webapp to map all /in/* requests to /*. If you want, you could make all those requests into 301 redirects, which imply that the resource has permanently moved. Well-behaved proxies and search engines should update their URLs accordingly.